# OWIN token authentication 400 Bad Request on OPTIONS from browser

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I am using token authentication for small project based on this article: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Everything seems to work fine except one thing: OWIN based token authentication doesn't allow OPTIONS request on /token endpoint. Web API returns 400 Bad Request and whole browser app stops sending POST request to obtain token.

I have all CORS enabled in application as in sample project. Below some code that might be relevant:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            app.UseWebApi(config);

            Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationContext.Initializer());
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
                RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
        }
    }
```

Below is my login function from javascript (I am using angularjs for that purpose)

```
var _login = function (loginData) {

        var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;

        data = data + "&client_id=" + ngAuthSettings.clientId;

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).success(function (response) {

        localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName, refreshToken: response.refresh_token, useRefreshTokens: true });
        _authentication.isAuth = true;
        _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;
        _authentication.useRefreshTokens = loginData.useRefreshTokens;

        deferred.resolve(response);

        }).error(function (err, status) {
            _logOut();
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    var _logOut = function () {

        localStorageService.remove('authorizationData');

        _authentication.isAuth = false;
        _authentication.userName = "";
        _authentication.useRefreshTokens = false;

    };
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was not sending with OPTIONS request header Access-Control-Request-Method

Comment: Was going to reply you, but you solved it, glad that my tutorial and code samples are useful :)

Comment: Same problem here. And I still haven't understood how to solve this.

Comment: I would have been nice if you elaborated on how you solved the issue.. I solved it using the solution posed by @knr

Comment: :) Nice solution.. but how ?

Answer (score 37):

I've lost some time on this problem today. Finally i think i've found a solution.

Override method inside your OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider:

```
public override Task MatchEndpoint(OAuthMatchEndpointContext context)
{
    if (context.IsTokenEndpoint && context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "authorization" });
        context.RequestCompleted();
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    return base.MatchEndpoint(context);
}
```

This appears to do three necessary things:

- Force auth server to respond to OPTIONS request with 200 (OK) HTTP status,
- Allow request to come from anywhere by setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
- Allows `Authorization` header to be set on subsequent requests by setting `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

After those steps angular finally behaves correctly when requesting token endpoint with OPTIONS method. OK status is returned and it repeats request with POST method to get full token data.

Comment: Thanks @knr, your solution works fine for me.
I also add the header "Allow" in the response, giving the list of HTTP verb admitted for the resources:

context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Allow", new[] { "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD" });

Comment: Once more, this answer saves me hours of bug tracking. Can't thank you enough +1M

Answer (score 1):

Override this method inside your `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`:

```
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it locally or are you publishing it to Azure like in the blog article's sample code?

If you're running it on Azure, you can easily fix CORS problems by enabling CORS in the Azure portal:

1. Click on your App Service in the Azure Portal to enter the management screen.
2. In the list of management options, scroll down to the 'API' section, where you will find the 'CORS' option.  (Alternatively type 'CORS' in the search box).
3. Enter the allowed origin, or enter '*' to enable all, and click save.

This fixed the OPTIONS preflight check problem for me, which a few other people seem to have had from the code in that particular blog article.

Answer (score -4):

This should do the trick:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Comment: Please explain a little, so that other users can understand the reason for the issue and how the solution works. Thanks :)